# Prevent react-native-webview from caching

Tags: react-native, webview

I'm using https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview with a React Native v0.60 project. I'm using it fairly simply to display a third party webpage,

```
<WebView source={{ uri }} />
```

When a user navigates to the page displaying the WebView, it loads content from the cache. I can confirm this using the iOS simulator and Safari debugging tools:

[image: CSS source is Memory Cache]

I see that WebView has a `cacheEnabled` property, but even using `<WebView source={{ uri }} cacheEnabled={false} />`, the contents are not updated, and Safari tools still indicate that the content is being loaded from the cache.

Is there anything additional that needs to be done or any way to either have WebView ignore the cache or force it to reload the content from the server?

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @NrN not exactly ... I spoke to the team working on the website and they updated it to use a hash on their asset files when there are changes to avoid reusing an older version from the cache.

Comment: guess its the server that has to disable cache.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and tried this (ie clear the cache before loading the page) and the problem stopped happening:

```
<WebView 
  cacheEnabled={false} 
  source={{ uri: 'https://www.flatpackamigos.co.uk/app/originalhome/' }}
  
/>
```